# unsual- get request result not updated after post request volley

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm new to both mobile development for android AND php so please go easy on me if my question is not relevant. Thanks.

The requirement is to develop a function to synchronize - upload and then download data, by clicking at button, from an android device sqlite database to mysql server on godaddy platform.

- I developed 2 seperate webservices: 1 for the upload function and 1 for the download function hosted on godaddy server
- I used volley's request apis
- I developed a synchelper class to upload and download function for android.

**PROBLEM** 
- The upload and download functions work fine when they are invoked on click by separate buttons, one after the other. But when I integrate the upload and download functions together into one button, the upload function works fine but the download function does not download the latest image of the mysql database which includes the data that has just been uploaded.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Here's my code:

In syncHelper.java

```
    String read_animal_url = "http://www.careagriculture.com/get_all_animals3.php";
    String insert_animals_url = "http://www.careagriculture.com/insert_animals25.php";
    public void DeviceDataUpload() {

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Method.POST, insert_animals_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        if (!(response == null)) {

                            JSONObject c = new JSONObject(response);
                            System.out.print(insert_animals_url + " response " + response.toString());
                            int success = c.getInt("success");
                            if (success == 1) {
                                localDBHelper.deleteAllAnimalFromDevice();

                            }
                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams(){
            Map<String, String> params = localDBHelper.getAllAnimalMap();
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Priority getPriority() {
            return Priority.HIGH;
        }
    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToReqQueue(postRequest);
}


    public void ServerDataDownload(){

    JsonObjectRequest readAnimalReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, read_animal_url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        System.out.print(read_animal_url+" response "+response.toString());
                        int success = response.getInt("success");

                        if (success == 1) {
                            JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("animal");

                            localDBHelper.deleteAllAnimalFromServer();

                            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                                map.put("ANIMAL_ID", c.getString(TAG_ANIMAL_ID));
                                map.put("SUPERVISOR", c.getString(TAG_SUPERVISOR));
                                map.put("ANIMAL_TYPE", c.getString(TAG_ANIMAL_TYPE));
                                map.put("RECORD_TYPE", "S");
                                if (!c.isNull(TAG_GENDER))
                                    map.put("GENDER", c.getString(TAG_GENDER));
                                if (!c.isNull(TAG_DATE_OF_BIRTH))
                                    map.put("DATE_OF_BIRTH", c.getString(TAG_DATE_OF_BIRTH));
                                if (!c.isNull(TAG_DATE_PURCHASED))
                                    map.put("DATE_PURCHASED", c.getString(TAG_DATE_PURCHASED));
                                if (!c.isNull(TAG_PURCHASE_PRICE))
                                    map.put("PURCHASE_PRICE", c.getString(TAG_PURCHASE_PRICE));
                                if (!c.isNull(TAG_DATE_DISTRIBUTED))
                                    map.put("DATE_DISTRIBUTED",  c.getString(TAG_DATE_DISTRIBUTED));
                                if (!c.isNull(TAG_DATE_SOLD))
                                    map.put("DATE_SOLD", c.getString(TAG_DATE_SOLD));
                                if (!c.isNull(TAG_SALE_PRICE))
                                    map.put("SALE_PRICE", c.getString(TAG_SALE_PRICE));

                                Item_List.add(map);
                                localDBHelper.insertAnimalFromServer(map);

                            } 
                        } 

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Priority getPriority() {
            return Priority.LOW;
        }
    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToReqQueue(readAnimalReq);
}
```

In MainActivity, I call:

```
syncButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (localDBHelper.getAllAnimalCount()>0) {
                SyncHelper syncHelper = new SyncHelper(MainActivity.this);
                syncHelper.DeviceDataUpload();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Upload Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            syncHelper.ServerDataDownload();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sync Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()` when uploading sounds like it is asynchronous, so will return immediately back to your click handler event.

If you want to trigger the download *after* your upload has completed, you need to call it from the onResponse() method in the upload's listener.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you! it's incredible and it worked. And thank you so much for explaining the behaviour too!